# IFS Report Designer - Register a new layout to the database

Tags: ifs, report-designer, ifs-erp

I am a student working for an IFS implementation project and currently learning how to use IFS Report Designer. However, I am stuck since my new layout is not shown in the drop down list when I try to print from Report Archive even though my new layout is created in Report Definitions and deployed successfully from IFS Report Designer.  Please help me with this issue. Many thanks.

P/s: I have tried to search for materials but nothing  available and from IFS side, they have no specific materials guide.

Comment: What is the version of IFS Applications & IFS Report Designer you are using?

Answer (score 0):

If you added it correctly to the report definition then it should work. Here are some steps to troubleshoot.

1. Close out all instances of IFS and log back in.
2. Make sure that the report title from the report archive and the report title from the report definition that you are making changes to are identical.
3. On the report definition screen, right click your layout and choose export layout to make sure you have it saved. Delete your layout and save. Recreate it by adding a new layout line. Fill out every single column and make sure the "In Use" box is checked. Save. Right click on the new line and choose import layout, and choose your layout file. Save.
4. Go and reprint the actual report from it's screen. For example if you added the new layout to Instant Invoice, then go to the instant invoice screen, populate it, right click and choose reprint original. This step will be different for different reports obviously as some reports and the screens they are used on have different names, and they right click options to print the report will be called different things. This is just an example.
5. Go back to the report archive, and try and print the new report you just printed, and see if the layout shows up.